# Code behaving differently in Production vs Locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have a Loopback app where I have created some seed scripts to pre-populate the db.

Here is the seed

```
const remote = {
    "name": "remote",
    "email": "remote@ttt.com",
    "password": "arglebargle"
}

app.models.AppUser.find({where: {email: 'remoteUser@ttt.com'}})
    .then(res => {
        if (res.length === 0) {
            createUsers(remote, 'remote')
        } else {
            console.log('remote user already exists')
        }
    })
```

This calls createUsers which is below

```
const app = require('../server')
const Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = {
  createUsers: (userInfo, roleName) => {
    if (!userInfo || !roleName) {
      let err = new Error('please give valid user and role names')
      console.log(err)
      return err
    }
    console.log(userInfo)
    return app.models.AppUser.findOrCreate({where: {'name': userInfo.name}}, userInfo)
      .then((instance) => {
        return app.models.Role.findOne({where: {name: roleName}})
          .then((role) => {
              return role.principals.create({
              principalType: app.models.RoleMapping.USER,
              principalId: instance[0].id //find or create returns an array
          })
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return error
      })
    }
  }
```

The above probably isn't good promise based code. But this is working fine in other situations so I am not sure if I can blame it.

Running the above script creates the 'remote' user and assigns the 'remote' role to it locally, however it does not do anything in production and I just cannot figure out why.

The only other difference I can think of between production and local is that the I am calling them from different locations (the project root is different)

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple issues here. First, in this block:

```
  createUsers: (userInfo, roleName) => {
    if (!userInfo || !roleName) {
      let err = new Error('please give valid user and role names')
      console.log(err)
      return err
    }
    console.log(userInfo)
    return app.models.AppUser.findOrCreate
```

you're returning an Error and a Promise from one function. Then here:

```
    if (res.length === 0) {
        createUsers(remote, 'remote')
    } else {
        console.log('remote user already exists')
    }
```

you're ignoring the return value altogether from `createUsers`

I'd stick with promises, as that seems to be the direction you're going, like so:

```
createUsers: (userInfo, roleName) => {
  if (!userInfo || !roleName) {
    let err = new Error('please give valid user and role names')
    console.log(err)
    return Promise.reject(err)
  }
  ...
```

and you *must handle* every promise, otherwise it will silently fail.

```
if (res.length === 0) {
  createUsers(remote, 'remote')
    .then(result => console.log('got a result'))
    .catch(error => console.error('oh no!', error))
} else ...
```

And also, the first AppUser.find is not being handled if there is an error:

```
app.models.AppUser.find({where: {email: 'remoteUser@ttt.com'}})
   .catch(err => console.error('yikes!', err))
   .then(res => {
```

The code you have *now* will silently swallow any errors that occur in createUsers or that first call. So, something like the database being unreachable in production would never present itself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Superb points. Also didn't know I could use Promise.reject(error) that is a great pointer. Will incorporate your suggestions and see if this works as expected in production.

Comment: thanks for your help. The problem turned out to be different. I needed to run migrations on the mysql table. There was a difference in them locally vs remotely. But loopback was itself silently swallowing errors. Which is quite bad. Will try and raise a bug report there.